# How to abbreviate "section" and "sections" in scientific writing

Tags: abbreviations, science, scientific-language

What are the correct abbreviation of words "section" and "sections" in a scientific writing?

> Sec. and Secs.

or

> Sect. and Sects.

?

Comment: There is the section sign '§', but obviously it is not appropriate here.

Comment: abbreviations.com gives everything from 'sec' to 'sxn'.   https://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviation/Section

Comment: I know people who would not hesitate to use § in the middle of a sentence for "section", and §§ for "sections".

Comment: What kind of scientific writing? Please give an example sentence. I have never encountered the problem in my field.

Comment: This cannot be answered in any particular way unless you provide a *specific* context. Some fields of study use a symbol, some a specific abbreviation, and others no abbreviation at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience you should avoid abbreviating it (in papers, textbooks and theses). Some style guides avoid abbreviating "figure", "equation" etc. even though those are much more common. On the rare occasions an abbreviation is used, it's never "sect." but "sec." (and in a few old texts, just "s."). "Sec" is an (incorrect) abbreviation for second, and "sect" is another word; neither is likely to lead to actual misunderstandings but can mean a sentence is unintuitive at first glance.

Comment: Agree avoid abbreviating (not saving that much space anyway), but "sect." is also acceptable, esp to distinguish from "sec." as in "secretary" ("secy." also valid there). An abbreviation's ending period (in addition to context) helps distinguish it from any whole word equivs (as u allude to).